# how to break the GRUB password?

Tags: 12.10, grub2, password

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. We all know that from the Restore option in the GRUB menu we can reset our lost password. We can also put password for GRUB to prevent other users ,to reset the password.

My question is that , is there any way we can break/reset the GRUB menu password , so that I can know protection of my PC.

Bottom-Line : How can we break/reset the GRUB menu password ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Boot the system with an Ubuntu live USB or DVD and try to switch to rescue mode. In rescue mode you will be asked if similar steps should be followed, which need to be followed in the installation. Once you get the # prompt, type the following command:

   `chmod /mnt/sysImage`
2. Edit the `grub.conf` file and remove the passwd line from the file. Save the file and exit.
3. Once your machine reboots, you will be able to start your Ubuntu in the usual manner.

Comment: Thank you but what I have to do in the case of No Live Device & another Computer with me.

Comment: @Jai You can try http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-forgotten-ubuntu-password-in-2-minutes-or-less/ . I can't say how good is this post currently.

Comment: well thats for reseting user password , my case is reseting the GRUB loader password.

Comment: Source: http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Security/Breaking_RESETTING_grub_password

Comment: I think you mean chroot /mnt/sysImage